# Display Select box in a column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dhtml

I am trying to display select box values in 4 columns. How can i do this. **I am going to use it on local server.**

I have got images to show you what i am trying to do.

**this is what i have got just now.**

[1 http://www.thewebdesign.org/1a.png](http://www.thewebdesign.org/1a.png)

**I am trying to turn into**

[2 http://www.thewebdesign.org/2a.png](http://www.thewebdesign.org/2a.png)

this is the code i am using

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--

.myselectbox {

    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;


}
    option {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 18px;
        background-color: #fef5e6;
        padding:8px;
        margin:5px;

        border-top: 1px solid #ebdac0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ebdac0;
        border-right: 1px solid #d6bb86;
        border-left: 1px solid #d6bb86;
    }
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<select name="amount_no1" class="myselectbox" id="amount_no1" >
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
</select> 
</center>
</body>
```

Comment: Not possible... how can u replace standard html element's nature ??

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible.  You'll have to use javascript to customize the select box.  Here are a list of jQuery plugins you can browse through:

[jQuery SelectBox Plugins](http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/03/11-jquery-plugins-to-enhance-html-dropdowns/)

Answer (score 0):

If that is the standart select element (not some kind of a plugin), I'm afraid it is not possible.

Comment: do you know any plugins i can use?

Answer (score 0):

JS code:

```
document.getElementById("amount_no1").value = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick attempt to modify your code. Not optimal, but I ran out of time

```
<style type="text/css">

.myselectbox {

    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;


}


ul {
  float: left;
  width: 12em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  float: left;
  width: 6em;
  font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 18px;
        background-color: #fef5e6;

      padding:8px;
        margin:5px;

        border-top: 1px solid #ebdac0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ebdac0;
        border-right: 1px solid #d6bb86;
        border-left: 1px solid #d6bb86;

} 
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<select name="amount_no1" class="myselectbox" id="amount_no1" onclick="document.getElementById('ul1').style.display='block'">
              <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<ul id="ul1" style="display:none"> 
              <li onclick="document.getElementById('amount_no1').options[0].text = 2;
              document.getElementById('ul1').style.display='none'">2</li>
              <li value="3">3</li>
              <li value="4">4</li>
              <li value="5">5</li>
              <li value="6">6</li>
              <li value="7">7</li>
              <li value="8">8</li>
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this plugin (http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown) for styled dropdown boxes, because it is not possible to style the standart dropdown box. The plugin contains a css file where you can specify your own styles if you want.